# перехват исключения производным классом

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, исключения

Объясните почему при вводе 0  и выбросе исключения `Base`, оно не отлавливается блоком `Derived1`?

```
int main()
{
    int number = 0;

    for (;;)
    {
        try
        {
            cin >> number;
            cout << number << " ";

            switch (number)
            {
                case 0:
                    throw Base();

                case 1:
                    throw Derived1();

                case 2:
                    throw Derived2();
            }
        }
        catch (Derived1 /*exception*/)
        {
            cout << "Exception of derived class" << endl;
        }
        catch (Base /*exception*/)
        {
            cout << "Exception of Base class" << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Потому что Base не является экземпляром Derived. Наоборот, Derived является экземпляром Base.

Comment: Вопрос звучит как "почему 2+2 не равно 5". Это вы сначала объясните, откуда вообще возник такой вопрос. С чего бы это вдруг `catch (Derived1)` станет ловить исключения типа `Base`?

Comment: @AnT: Подключайте телепатию :) Очевидно, ТС перепутала направление отношения _is-a_.

Comment: хорошо отредактировали: догадаться что от кого наследует только по названиям классов(((

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что `Base` **не** *является* `Derived`, а вот `Derived` *является* `Base`.

Вот если бы вы написали (кстати, перехватывайте исключения по ссылке, иначе столкнетесь со *срезкой*)

```
    catch (Base& /*exception*/)
    {
        cout << "Exception of Base class" << endl;
    }
    catch (Derived1& /*exception*/)
    {
        cout << "Exception of derived class" << endl;
    }
```

то тут и `Base`, и `Derived` ловились бы первым блоком - `Base`.